# How to move to last character of the file in vim?

Tags: vim

File:

```
i am someone1.
i am someone2.
i am someone3
~
~
```

Documentation says `G` takes me end of the file, but it only takes me to the beginning of last line. I want to be able to come to last character of the file, 3 in this case, and press `a` and type a period.

How do I do that?

Comment: This might be helpful: [How to make vim go to last line last character and then in insert mode?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11913788/939986)

Answer (score 46, accepted):

If you type `A` after `G` you will enter insert mode at the end of the last line.

If you just want to go to the last character, then `G-End` will suffice

Comment: `A` then `G` is fine for me. But if I don't want to edit, is `G-End` the only option? Is there a single key to do this instead of two?

Comment: Not that I am aware of, but that is no guarantee. You can always create your own map if you like.

Answer (score 41):

`G` goes to the last line and `$` goes to the last character of the line, so

```
G$
```

Comment: Gilles, Thanks this is more of what I was looking for.

Comment: Thanks. It's worth clarifying it's a capital G: `Shift`+`g`

Answer (score 8):

Ctrl+End also works, in both normal and insert modes. `:help <C-End>`

Comment: This only moves the cursor to the last character in the current line.

Comment: @sebix: No, check the help.

Comment: Does not work for me with vim 7.4

Comment: @sebix: It works for me just fine, and the help text is pretty clear. Maybe you have some mapping or plugin that is overriding the built-in behavior.

Answer (score 3):

- Move to last line in file: <kbd>G</kbd>
- Move to first line in file: <kbd>1</kbd><kbd>G</kbd>
- Move to end of line: <kbd>$</kbd>
- Move to beginning of line: <kbd>^</kbd>

Comment: Welcome to U&L, this hardly add anything to existing and accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the answers here assume a non-blank last line of the file - which is likely the most common case. There are also assumptions about the availability of an **END** key on one's keyboard. However, **END** keys are not universally available and blank lines are possible at the end of a file. Therefore the following can be leveraged for all cases to find the last (non-end-of-line) character of a file:

```
?[0-9a-zA-Z]
```

This is merely **one** of a few (or perhaps several) command combinations that can achieve the intended result. The pattern being:

```
"Set Cursor Position" + "Search Method" + "Pattern"
```

In the case of the above command sequence, you go to the beggining of the file and do a reverse search for any digit or letter.

Answer (score 0):

you can use large number such as 99 or 999 and $. like 999$

Comment: This is more keystrokes than `G$` and less certain.  Many files are longer than 1000 lines.

Comment: Agree, but this solution open a possibility that you can position to the end of any lines, say you can position to the end of line 13. You can do 13$.

Answer (score 0):

Using Vimscript:

```
:call search('\%$')
```

Reference: `:help \%$`

> %$   Matches end of the file.